# Binding using FFImageLoading.Cross.MvxCachedImageView in iOS

Tags: mvvmcross, oneway, ffimageloading

I'm using `FFImageLoading.Cross.MvxCachedImageView` and trying to make conditional binding in iOS, but it fails with the following Mvx trace:

> Problem seen during binding execution for binding Image for MvxValueConverterValueCombiner combiner-operation - problem ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'UIKit.UIImage'.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

```
set.Bind(imgInfo)
        .For(x => x.DataLocationUri)
        .OneWay()
        .SourceDescribed(@"If(IsFake, 'res:ic_lock_open_white', 'res:ic_info_outline_white')");
```

Comment: Does FFImageLoading DataLocationUri support `res:`?

Comment: I was using res: in Android and it was working as expected. This is the code:
local:MvxBind="DataLocationUri If(IsFavorite, 'res:ic_star_black', 'res:ic_star_border_black')"

Here is the proof (take look at line 416): 
https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/blob/master/source/FFImageLoading.Cross/MvxCachedImageView.cs